# How can I appeal against a moderator decision?

Tags: support, moderators

I've asked this question: [Is it possible to use my PS Vita as additional PS3 controller?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/104500/is-it-possible-to-use-my-ps-vita-as-additional-ps3-controller)

As I just noticed, my question got marked as duplicate by a moderator, so that it is not open to accept answers any more. In this specific case I described in the original question, that I am not looking for "Cross Play" or "Remote Play" features, the moderators' "duplicate" question aims:

> I've also tried to connect to the PS3 system using remote play and add the other controllers, but this did not work either, because the screen just says that my Vita is connected using remote play. "Cross Play" is also not what I am looking for. I just want to use my Vita like a traditional controller.

So in my opinion the moderator has not fully understood my question and spuriously marked it as a duplicate. I do not want to denounce somebody, all I want to know is:

1. What would be the correct way to discuss such cases?
2. If the "right" way is editing the question, does the moderator somehow recognize my edit and can remove the duplicate mark?

Sorry, if this question has been asked before. I did not find any references in the FAQ since I think this issue is pretty specific.

Comment: You appeal the decision by doing exactly what you did; open a question on Meta describing the situation.

Comment: Strix has the right of it. Meta is the right place for questions like this.

Comment: From looking over both questions, they do seem to be discussing the same thing.  The answers also look like they could be applied equally to either question.  That's usually a good indication that it's a dupe.  Am I missing something?

Comment: If you think it's something obvious that was missed, flag for "other" and fill in an explanation.  If it's more nuanced or warrants community discussion then Meta is the place.

Comment: @fbueckert: Take a look at the answer in the other question. It describes what Cross-Play and Remote-Play is. However both features are not compareable to using a PS Vita as an additional PS3 Controller, like I want to do. This is why both questions are aiming for similar, but basicly different topics!

Comment: Ah, yes.  That question is specifically about Remote Play.  I had misread it as, "Can I use Remote Play to use Vita as an extra controller."  That is specific to Remote Play.

Answer (score 3):

There is no formalized appeal process; this is not a tribunal and our actions are not jury orders. 3kers can reopen what we close and viceversa.

You can bring attention to the matter either via [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) or meta.

Any edit bumps the question to the top of the homepage. This is another way to bring attention to your question; one reopen vote brings it into the [reopen votes review queue](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/reopen) for further community scrutiny, too. (For the record, [your post has already gone through the review queue once](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/27468).)

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) What about my second question? I've edited the question, so does the moderator see my edit to be able to review it?